# jscrollpane in a jpanel

Tags: java, jpanel, jscrollpane

I want to have a scrollpane inside a panel while the scrollpane covers the whole panel. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure the JPanel has a BorderLayout, then add the JScrollPane to the BorderLayout.CENTER constraint.  Of course, don't add anything else to the NORTH/E/W/S constraints.